# In java.time.Period class, what are the purposes of withDays(), withMonths(), withYears()

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I noticed that the java.time.Period class contains a few instance methods that behave the same as the available static factory methods.

- `.withDays()` behaves the same as `Period.ofDays()`
- `.withMonths()` behaves the same as `Period.ofMonths()`
- `.withYears()` behaves the same as `Period.ofYears()`

These instance methods are confusing in that they create a new Period and return them, but without taking into consideration the state of the Period they are called on.

```
Period p = Period.ofWeeks(3);
p = p.withDays(2);
```

It seems logical that this would return a period of 3 weeks, 2 days, but it returns only a period of 2 days. This is the same as if I'd called `Period.ofDays(2)`.

Also, there are five other static factory methods without analogous instance methods.

So, is there a reason that these three instance methods would exist? If so, what's the use case?

Comment: There is no such method as `withWeeks` in `java.time.Period`class. You are probably mixed up them with `org.joda.time.Period` class

Comment: @Andremoniy: Um, really? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#withDays-int- Which method referred to above doesn't exist in `java.time.Period`?

Comment: @JonSkeet not really, `withDays`and `withYears` exist, but not `withWeeks`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir there is no `withWeeks` method it's `withDays`

Comment: @Andremoniy: Ah, yes, that *one* method - but the rest of the 6 are present, and the question is entirely reasonable IMO. I'll edit out the first bullet...

Comment: @JonSkeet in any way, I'm not a downvoter

Comment: In fact, given the *title*, it looks like `withWeeks` was basically a typo for `withMonths`. Edited to make ti all make sense.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made a mistake with the withWeeks. I meant withDays, withMonths, and withYears.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You made an unfortunate choice to test with, basically - "weeks" isn't an independent unit; it's just a shorthand for 7 days. From the docs for `ofWeeks`:

> The resulting period will be day-based, with the amount of days equal to the number of weeks multiplied by 7. The years and months units will be zero.

When you then call `withDays`, that's effectively "overwriting" the number of days in the result, going from 21 days to 2 days.

So try this instead:

```
Period p = Period.ofMonths(3);
p = p.withDays(2);
```

This now *will* be 3 months and 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

In java-8 new Date API, it's a rule maybe, the method start with `of` means create or new a Object, usually a static method, and the method start with `with` means modify some attribute, usually a object method.

so `Period.ofDays(2)` means create a Period which attribute days is 2, but `withDays(2)` means modify a Period attribute days to new value 2.

They have a different role.